# Create Numpy Array of All Possible Squared Differences Between Matrix of Vectors

Tags: numpy

I have a numpy array X with shape (1,100,2406). This is 2406 vectors, where each vector is 100 dimensional.

I want to create a matrix that has shape (2406,2406) where I have every possible squared difference.

For example, if we imagine a smaller case with just 3 vectors $v_1,v_2,v_3 \in \mathbb{R}^{100}$, my original array (with singleton dimension suppressed) looks like

$begin{pmatrix} v_1 & v_2 & v_3 \end{pmatrix}

I want to construct the following (in this case it would be a 3x3 matrix):

$\begin{pmatrix} ||v_1-v_1||^2 & ||v_1-v_2||^2 & ||v_1-v_3||^2 \ ||v_2-v_1||^2 & ||v_2-v_2||^2 & ||v_2-v_3||^2 \ ||v_3-v_1||^2 & ||v_3 - v_2||^2 & ||v_3-v_3||^2 \end{pmatrix}$

I am confused with the shapes.

I think I need to reshape the original array and then do a subtraction that will give the correct shape but I don't really have any intuition as to how I should reshape it?

Comment: Check out https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.cdist.html

Answer (score 0):

```py
import numpy as np

def pairwise_dist(Y):
  '''
  Accept Y with shape (n_vectors, vector_dim)
  '''
  return np.linalg.norm(Y[None, :, :] - Y[:, None, :], axis=-1)

pairwise_dist(X[0].T)
```

Numpy will reshape for you while broadcasting `Y[None, :, :]` and `Y[:, None, :]`.